# how to connect appjs to nodejs server and show its content

Tags: node.js, express

I want to show the content of my website in the appjs window, but I dont know how.

In the appjs script there are 
`app.serveFilesFrom(__dirname + '/content');`
to say where the content is, that it has to show, but I dont want it local, I want it to show the content of my website, running by a node.js serverscript.

I have tried this
https://github.com/appjs/appjs/wiki/Using-express-to-handle-local-http-requests
and some of the methods from the express.js documentation but unsuccessfully.

Therefore I ask here, have somebody an idea, how to do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to download remote content from your website with your `Node.js` app and deliver the content with it?

Comment: No, not download. As if the browser would be app.js. It just show the content from my node server.

Answer (score 2):

To have you website displayed within AppJS window like a web browser, which is one of the primary intents of AppJS, you can take any one of these two (2) steps;

1. Create an IFRAME (that fills up the width and height) in the index.html
   file located at "data/content/".

   Set the IFRAME SRC to your website url.

   e.g. < iframe src="http://www.YourWebsite.com">

   This will display your website in AppJS window when app.exe is started.

   NOTE: You might want to use CSS to make the iframe fill up 100%
   width and 100% height of the window.
2. Change the line of code at "data/node_modules/appjs/lib/settings.js"

   FROM

   url :'ht tp://appjs',

   TO

   url: 'http://www.YourWebsite.com'

Most of the time I opt for the first option as it allows me do a whole lot of things using CSS. And this includes placing an animated GIF at the background of the IFRAME to indicate page loading at start up.

I go for the second option only when I want to make my actual website url a little trickier to find during an attempted hack. While still leaving the "data/content" directory and its content undeleted.

I hope this answers.

Comment: Thumbs up for easy and clean iframe solution

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly, you can actually make a proxy request and pipe it's response to your app response.

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var options = {
    host: "stackoverflow.com",
    port: 80,
    path: "/",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {}
};

app.get("/stackoverflow*", function (request, response) {
    "use strict";

    var proxyRequest;

    options.headers.cookie = request.headers.cookie;
    options.headers["user-agent"] = request.headers["user-agent"];

    // TODO set other headers if needed

    options.path = "/" + request.path.split("/").slice(2).join("/");
    options.method = request.method;

    proxyRequest = http.request(options, function (proxyResponse) {
        proxyResponse.pipe(response);
    });

    request.pipe(proxyRequest);
}).listen(8080);
```

Now you can navigate to `http://localhost:8080/stackoverflow/questions/14880557/how-to-connect-appjs-to-nodejs-server-and-show-its-content/14890268#14890268` and your app will show the requested path from `stackoverflow.com`.