# AppJs as Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, chromium, appjs

i have recently developped a Web Application running on node.js available online on nodejitsu. Now my client wants to have a standalone Desktop Application and my thoughts were on AppJS. So the question now is, is there a way on using AppJS as a "Browser" since its based on Chromium. This would be neat, because the complete App Logic and the Frontend is on the Server, so I don't have to do more than just refer the AppJS to the URL. The DesktopApp Feeling would be serverd and a navigation is all within the Frontend. No needs of back and forward browser buttons or adressbar.

So much for the goal. I tried this simply by redirecting the AppJS index.html to my server URL. And the first site showed fine, but as i tried to log in, this error encountered:

```
app.sh: line 4:  1734 Bus error: 10           $basedir/data/bin/node --harmony $basedir/data/app.js
```

Any suggestions ? Is this possible with AppJS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your question is similar to what i answered in a previous post ([how to connect appjs to nodejs server and show its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880557/how-to-connect-appjs-to-nodejs-server-and-show-its-content/15407709#15407709)). So, I'm gonna just repeat the same here with hope that it answers your need.

Yes, it is possible to have AppJS serve as a browser for your website.

To have you website displayed within AppJS window like a web browser, which is one of the primary intents of AppJS, you can take any one of these two (2) steps;

1. Create an IFRAME (that fills up the width and height) in the index.html file located at "data/content/".

   Set the IFRAME SRC to your website url.

   e.g. < iframe src="http://www.YourWebsite.com">

   This will display your website in AppJS window when app.exe is started.

   NOTE: You might want to use CSS to make the iframe fill up 100% width and 100% height of the window.
2. Change the line of code at "data/node_modules/appjs/lib/settings.js"

   FROM

   url :'ht tp://appjs',

   TO

   url: 'http://www.YourWebsite.com'

Most of the time I opt for the first option as it allows me do a whole lot of things using CSS. And this includes placing an animated GIF at the background of the IFRAME to indicate page loading at start up.

I go for the second option only when I want to make my actual website url a little trickier to find during an attempted hack. While still leaving the "data/content" directory and its content undeleted.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks ! I figured out the iframe solution but for me it looked more like a work around, because of the lags I had displaying the different sites.

Comment: do you have access to that iframe?